# jquery/Javascript using this to get ID name and plug and concatenate for string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am ultimately trying to automate a function that will fade in and out an image for every different piece of text on a menu. I could make a function for every single thing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nd').hover(function() {
        $('#ndimg').fadeTo('fast',1)
    }, function() {
        $('#ndimg').fadeTo('fast',0);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to automate this by using "this" and getting the ID string to concatenate, assuming I have all the image Divs named in a corresponding pattern so that this would work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).hover(function() {
        var imageid = this.id;
        $('#' + imageid +'img').fadeTo('fast',1)
    }, function() {
        $('#' + imageid +'img').fadeTo('fast',0);
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML document snippet:

```
<div class="workmenu">
    <ul>
        <li id="nd">Nora & Danny Show</li>
        <li id ="tg"> Teagan George</li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class="logos"
    <div id="ndimg">
        <img src = "nd.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML. If you are asking how to selected specific elements we have to know how the document structure actually looks like. Also you have a syntax error in the fourth line.

Comment: If you are going to use hover, you need to use an element with :hover, otherwise use mouseover and mouseout... and you probably want to do it with a class rather than everything in the document.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- You are not binding the event handler to the correct element
- You are not defining all variables you need

You have to bind the event handler to the `li` elements, not to `document`:

```
$('.workmenu li').hover(...);
```

In your mouseout event handler, `imageid` is not defined, as you can see in the console when you debug your code. Define it:

```
$('.workmenu li').hover(function() {
    var imageid = this.id;
    $('#' + imageid +'img').fadeTo('fast',1)
}, function() {
    var imageid = this.id;
    $('#' + imageid +'img').fadeTo('fast',0);
});
```